# remove all the products that their expiary date is after a given date

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `Date` class, that has _day, _month, and _year properties.
I also have a `FoodItem` class, that one of its properties is the expiry date of the item. (from type `Date`)

Now I am creating a method to remove from an array of `FoodItem` named `_stock`, all the items that their expiry date is after a Date passed as a parameter.

This is an assignment so I may not use any advanced java objects such as ArrayLists.

two methods I can use, that are located in the class Date are `before` and `after`:

```java
public boolean before(Date other) {
        if (_year < other.getYear())
            return true;
        if (_month < other.getMonth() && _year == other.getYear())
            return true;
        if (_day < other.getDay() && _month == other.getMonth() && _year == other.getYear())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean after(Date other) {
        return other.before(this);
    }
```

I have tried the followings:

```java
public void removeAfterDate(Date d)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <_noOfFoodItems; i++)
            /*if item's expiry date is after the given date,
             it will be deleted*/
            if (_stock[i].getExpiryDate().before(d) /*also tried _stock[i].getExpiryDate().after(d), d.before(_stock[i].getExpiryDate()) and d.after(_stock[i].getExpiryDate())*/)
                fillHoles(i);
    }
    private void fillHoles(int index)
    {
        //since the function deletes an item, the _noOfFoodItems counter should go down by 1
        _noOfFoodItems--;
        /*this will place each item, starting from the given index,
        * one location in the array before where it currently is.
        * this action will override the item that need to be deleted, while
        * filling the "holes" created in the array becuse of the deleted item*/
        for (int i = index; i < _noOfFoodItems; i++)
        {
            _stock[i] = _stock[i + 1];
            _stock[i + 1] = null;
        }
    }
```

But when run the following tester:

```java
new Test("removeAfterDate()", () -> {
                Date date1 = new Date(1, 1, 2000);
                Date date2 = new Date(1, 2, 2000);
                Date date3 = new Date(1, 3, 2000);
                Date date4 = new Date(1, 4, 2000);
                FoodItem fi1 = new FoodItem("Name1", 1001, 1, date1,/*expiary date:*/ date2, 1, 10, 5);
                //only this one should stay
                FoodItem fi2_fresh = new FoodItem("Name2", 1002, 1, date1, /*expiary date:*/ date4, 5, 10, 5);
                FoodItem fi3 = new FoodItem("Name3", 1003, 1, date1,/*expiary date:*/ date2, 1, 10, 5);
                FoodItem fi4 = new FoodItem("Name4", 1004, 1, date1,/*expiary date:*/ date2, 1, 10, 5);
                //this is the class removeAfterDate is located in
                Stock actual = new Stock();
                // this just add the items to the _stock array
                actual.addItem(fi1);
                actual.addItem(fi2_fresh);
                actual.addItem(fi3);
                actual.addItem(fi4);

                actual.removeAfterDate(date3);
                //line 145
                assertEquals(actual, new FoodItem[]{fi2_fresh});
                //line 147
                assertEquals(actual.getNumOfItems(), 1);
            })
```

I get the errors :

```
removeAfterDate(): 2 errors
        At line 145: Expected:
[FoodItem: Name2    CatalogueNumber: 1002   ProductionDate: 01/01/2000  ExpiryDate: 01/04/2000  Quantity: 1
]
But got:
[FoodItem: Name2    CatalogueNumber: 1002   ProductionDate: 01/01/2000  ExpiryDate: 01/04/2000  Quantity: 1
FoodItem: Name4 CatalogueNumber: 1004   ProductionDate: 01/01/2000  ExpiryDate: 01/02/2000  Quantity: 1
]

        At line 147: Expected 1 but got 2
```

what have I done wrong?

Comment: If an array contains [1, 2, 3], and you're at index 0, and remove it, you get[2, 3, null]. Then you go at index 1, and inspect the value 3. That means you never inspected the value 2. Loop from the end to the beginning.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right, this is probably the source of the error